# calling a method in a smali file using and passing ApplicationContext

Tags: android, smali, apktool

I am a beginner in smali world. 
I will show the JAVA bit code viewer and the smali code of the class, and what is the call I want to add.
**Java Code:**

```
public final 0ai A0J(2cO param2cO)
  {
    0Ep local0Ep = this.A01;
    0q5 local0q5 = new 0q5(local0Ep);
    local0q5.A09 = 001.A01;
    Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[2];
    int i = param2cO.A04.size();
    String str1 = "1";
    String str2 = "0";
    if (i > 0) {
      str2 = str1;
    }
    arrayOfObject[0] = str2;
    if (param2cO.A06.size() <= 0) {
      str1 = "0";
    }
    arrayOfObject[1] = str1;
    local0q5.A0E("media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s", arrayOfObject); // I want to replace the string with a method call;
    local0q5.A0E = true;
    String str3 = 2cO.A00(param2cO.A04);
    String str4 = 2cO.A00(param2cO.A07);
    String str5 = 2cO.A01(param2cO.A05);
    .......
```

**The Smali Code**

```
.method public final A0J(LX/2cO;)LX/0ai;
    .locals 10

    .line 0
    iget-object v4, p0, LX/1dt;->A01:LX/0Ep;

    .line 1
    .line 2
    new-instance v3, LX/0q5;

    .line 3
    .line 4
    invoke-direct {v3, v4}, LX/0q5;-><init>(LX/0UX;)V

    .line 5
    .line 6
    .line 7
    sget-object v0, LX/001;->A01:Ljava/lang/Integer;

    .line 8
    .line 9
    iput-object v0, v3, LX/0q5;->A09:Ljava/lang/Integer;

    .line 10
    .line 11
    const/4 v0, 0x2

    .line 12
    new-array v6, v0, [Ljava/lang/Object;

    .line 13
    .line 14
    iget-object v0, p1, LX/2cO;->A04:Ljava/util/HashMap;

    .line 15
    .line 16
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/util/HashMap;->size()I

    .line 17
    .line 18
    .line 19
    move-result v0

    .line 20
    const-string v5, "1"

    .line 21
    .line 22
    const-string v2, "0"

    .line 23
    .line 24
    move-object v1, v2

    .line 25
    if-lez v0, :cond_0

    .line 26
    .line 27
    move-object v1, v5

    .line 28
    :cond_0
    const/4 v0, 0x0

    .line 29
    aput-object v1, v6, v0

    .line 30
    .line 31
    const/4 v1, 0x1

    .line 32
    iget-object v0, p1, LX/2cO;->A06:Ljava/util/HashMap;

    .line 33
    .line 34
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/util/HashMap;->size()I

    .line 35
    .line 36
    .line 37
    move-result v0

    .line 38
    if-gtz v0, :cond_1

    .line 39
    .line 40
    move-object v5, v2

    .line 41
    :cond_1
    aput-object v5, v6, v1

    .line 42
    .line 43
    const-string v0, "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s"

    .line 44
    .line 45
    invoke-virtual {v3, v0, v6}, LX/0q5;->A0E(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V

    .line 46
    .line 47
    .line 48
    const/4 v2, 0x1
```

I created a java method which will be the one I want to call/invoke :

```
public String is_story_mode(Context paramContext)
{

    SharedPreferences story_mod_mem = paramContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("story_mod", 0);

    if(story_mod_mem.getString("story_mod", "").contains("on"))
    {

        return "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s";
    }else{
        return "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s";
    }
   }
```

The Smali code of the method "**is_story_mode**"

```
.method public is_story_mode(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
    .registers 4

    .line 23
    invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v0, "story_mod"

    const/4 v1, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getSharedPreferences(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;

    move-result-object p1

    .line 25
    const-string v0, "story_mod"

    const-string v1, ""

    invoke-interface {p1, v0, v1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;->getString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v0, "on"

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z

    move-result p1

    if-eqz p1, :cond_1e

    .line 27
    const-string p1, "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s"

    return-object p1

    .line 29
    :cond_1e
    const-string p1, "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s"

    return-object p1
.end method
```

I tried a lot of ways to make the invoke, but each time i got force close.
What is the correct way to do this :

```
local0q5.A0E(is_story_mode(this), arrayOfObject);
```

Comment: A "force close" as you call it is almost always due to an exception. If you look in logcat at the time that the exception occurs, you'll see an error message and stack trace with more information about exactly why and where the exception occurred. That should be the first thing you look at (and include in your question) in a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Replace :

```
const-string v0, "media/seen/?reel=%s&live_vod=%s"
```

With:

```
.line 42
.line 43
invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, LX/1eG;->is_story_mode()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new-array v1 v0 [Ljava/lang/Class;
const-class v2 Ljava/util/ArrayList;
const/4 v3 0 
aput-object v2 v1 v3
const-class v2 Ljava/io/File;
const/4 v4 1 
aput-object v2 v1 v4
const-string v2 ""
invoke-static {} Lcn/beingyi/sub/apps/SubApp/SubApplication$ˆ;->SLGpJיᵢˊיˈיˆʾˎˋﹶˉᐧʼˊﾞᵔᐧˉᴵⁱʿˑʻˎˈˋʻˆuROfn()Ljava/lang/String;
move-result-object v2
invoke-static {v5,v2,v1} Lˆ/ʿ/ʿ/ˈ/ʿ/ʿ/ʿ/ˆ;->ʿ(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
move-result-object v1
new-array v0 v0 [Ljava/lang/Object;
aput-object v6 v0 v3
aput-object v7 v0 v4
invoke-virtual {v1,v5,v0} Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;->invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
move-result-object v0
check-cast v0 [Ljava/lang/Object;
return-object v0
```

Comment: Hey, can you please provide context for this answer? It's easier for others when you explain why this could solve the problem. :)